# How to remove image url from sitemap.xml Magento 2?

Tags: product-images, catalog, magento-2.1.8, sitemaps, image-url

I have created sitemap.xml in the website. In which, Image URL coming with cdn link.

I have change setting from admin but still is showing.

I don't want to use CDN URL in the sitemap.

How to remove product image URLs from the sitemap.xml?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any *custom code to disable the image from sitemap.xml*.

Magento has a ***setting at admin from where you can disable product image from the sitemap.***

Logging at admin.

Then navigate to **`STORE>Configuration>Catalog>XML Sitemap>Products Options`**

and here you see a  setting **Add Images into Sitemap** and Make it to**NO** to remove images from the sitemap.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was doing a mistake. Old sitemap needs to delete from the website.